# Conflict between 'groovy' and 'grails-web' plugin gradle

Tags: grails, gradle, plugins, groovy, grails3

I'm working on the multi gradle projects.

One of the module is the `grails3` (3.1.4) project, which is generated using `create-app`, which had these default set of plugins.

```
apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
```

I've added a `groovy` plugin with that set.

```
apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"
apply plugin:"groovy"   <----- this has been appended at the last
```

but if I try to run it after applying it it shows the below error.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.gradle.groovy']cies ':agent' >
>   Resolving depen> Configuring > 1/1 projects > Resolving dependencies
>   ':agent' > Resolving depen
>
> > C> figuring > 1/1 projects > Resolving dependencies ':agent' > Resolving depen> ConCannot add task ':groovydoc' as a task with that
> >     name already exists.

It seems `grails-web` and `groovy` plugins have the same task name for `groovydoc`.

Is there any way we can apply tasks of `groovy` plugins some other way, or we can apply both the plugins together with some configurations?

Comment: `GrailsGradlePlugin` extends `GroovyPlugin`.  Why is it that you would want to explicitly add the `groovy` plugin?

Comment: You're right @JeffScottBrown, I misunderstood the context to add the `groovy` plugin. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way we can apply tasks of groovy plugins some other way...

The tasks of the `groovy` plugin will already be available. `GrailsGradlePlugin` extends `GroovvyPlugin`.